# Bottom bar of android nexus 9 won't hide on javascript fullscreen api

Tags: javascript, android, html, fullscreen

I'm developing a full screen HTML app for android, it works all right on all the devices I have tested except the latest nexus 9.

The problem is that the the bottom bar is not hidden on the nexus 9, the softkey icons hide but not the bar itself. Chrome does not seem to recognise this, so the app consumes the entire display but the home menu bar at the bottom just lays over on top of everything. It even lays on top of chrome notifications like allowing access to microphone.

The URL bar, tabs, and android status bar with time, battery life, and network strength is hidden properly as expected. Just the black bar remains.

Any ideas what this is? Seems like a bug.